# Suggest appropriate mysql date function

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

I'm having a date field of datatype `datetime`,even though `H:s:i` is stored but I don't want take into consideration in validations for that I'm using `CURDATE()` in where condition of query but 'H:S:i' is being considering, for example

```
SELECT ('2013-01-10 05:10:50' <= CURDATE()) FROM dual
```

Above query returns false(0),why not true(1) because `2013-01-10 05:10:50` is a past time. In short, I want to store 'H:s:i' but should not consider while validating for that which MySql function will be suitable ?

**Updated below content**

I don't want use `NOW()` and `SYSDATE()` because these functions will consider `H:s:i` while validating,So that I've used `CURDATE()` but expected result is differ when I'm using `CURDATE()`.

Comment: CURDATE() returns '2013-01-10'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DATE('2013-01-10 05:10:50') <= CURDATE() FROM DUAL;

SELECT '2013-01-10 05:10:50' <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, above query will be fine when I'm using dual table,Suppose I'm having ` select * from table_name where date_field1 <= CURDATE()`,here date_field1 value is '2013-01-10 05:10:50'.

Comment: You can easily do this. SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE(date_field1) <= CURDATE() using this query

Comment: Thanks its return expected output,if is there other alternatives then suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

Your query return `false` because `CURDATE()` returns a **date** not the date and time. Just returning a date means `2012-01-10 00:00:00` when being compared with a date and time. Thus `CURDATE()` is not before `2013-01-10 05:10:50`.

I suggest you use `NOW()` - which does return a date and time.

[Docs for `NOW()` here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

Answer (score 2):

`CURDATE()` does not include a time, so it will therefore be 00:00:00 or midnight on the 9th/10th boundary. If you want to do this check use `NOW()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Use `now()` instead of `curdate()`.

`now()` returns the current date *and time*, whereas `curdate()` returns the current date which is cast to a daterime for the comparison and goven a time component if `00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use now() or current_timestamp